# find specific child in xml

Tags: python, xml, indexing, attributes

```
<graphiceditor>
    <plot name="DS_Autobahn 1.Track: Curvature &lt;78.4204 km>" type="CurvePlot">
        <parent>DS_Autobahn 1</parent>
        ...
        <curve name="" isXTopAxis="0" markerSize="8" symbol="-1" 
            <point x="19.986891478960015" y="-0.00020825890723451596"/>
            <point ....
```

Hello, I want to open the .xml file, find "curve" and import the y-coordinate of the curve into a list. I know that "curve" has the index [16] so I am using this right now:

```
tree = ET.parse(file_name)
root = tree.getroot()    
curvature = [float(i) for i in[x["y"] for x in [root[0][16][i].attrib for i in range(len(root[0][16]))]]]
```

But how do I do it, if curve is not at the 16th position? How do I find curve in any xml file then? I have been trying for several hours now but I simply do not get it. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPath for instance.

This would then essentially look like:

`root.findall(xpath)`

where your xpath would be './/curve' if you are just interested in all childs of tag-type curve.

For more inofrmation regarding xpath see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning about Regular Expressions (more commonly referred to as Regex), I use them all the time for problems like this.

This is a good place to reference the different aspects of Regex:
[Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Regex is a way to match text, its a lot like `if "substring" in string:` except a million times more powerful. The entire purpose of regex is to find that "substring" even when you don't know what it is.

So lets take a closer look at your example in particular, first thing to do is figure out exactly which rules need to be true in order to "match" the y value.
I don't know exactly how you are actually reading in your data, but am reading it in as a single string.

```
string = '<graphiceditor>' \
    '<plot name="DS_Autobahn 1.Track: Curvature &lt;78.4204 km>" type="CurvePlot">' \
    '<parent>DS_Autobahn 1</parent>' \
    '<curve name="" isXTopAxis="0" markerSize="8" symbol="-1"' \
    '<point x="19.986891478960015" y="-0.00020825890723451596"/>' \
    '<point ....'
```

You can see I split the sting into multiple lines to make it more readable. If you are reading it from a file with open() make sure to remove the "\n" meta-characters or my regex wont work (not that you cant write regex that would!)

The first thing I want to do is find the curve tag, then I want to continue on to find the y= section, then grab just the number. Let's simplify that out into really defined steps:

1. Find where the curve section begins
2. Continue until the next y= section begins
3. Get the value from inside the quotes after the y= section.

Now for the regex, I could explain how exactly it works but we would be here all day. Go back to that Doc I linked at the start and read-up.

```
import re
string = "[see above]"
y_val = re.search('<curve.*?y="(.*?)"', string).group(1)
```

That's it! Cast your y_val to a float() and you are ready to go!

Answer (score 0):

[Use an XML parser to parse XML; not regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/317052)

Like mentioned in another answer, I would also use XPath. If you need to use complex XPaths, I'd recommend using lxml. In your example though ElementTree will suffice.

For example, this Python...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("file_name.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
curvature = [float(y) for y in [point.attrib["y"] for point in root.findall(".//curve/point[@y]")]]

print(curvature)
```

using this XML ("file_name.xml")...

```
<graphiceditor>
    <plot name="DS_Autobahn 1.Track: Curvature &lt;78.4204 km>" type="CurvePlot">
        <parent>DS_Autobahn 1</parent>
        <curve name="" isXTopAxis="0" markerSize="8" symbol="-1">
            <point x="19.986891478960015" y="-0.00020825890723451596"/>
            <point x="19.986891478960015" y="-0.00030825690983451678"/>
        </curve>
    </plot>
</graphiceditor>
```

will print...

```
[-0.00020825890723451596, -0.0003082569098345168]
```

Note: Notice the difference between the second y coordinate in the list and what's in the XML. That's because you're casting the value to a float. Consider casting to a decimal if you need to maintain precision.